# bootstrap 4 navbar change menu position

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="fixed-top">
    <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-dark p-4">
        <h5 class="text-white h4">Collapsed content</h5>
        <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
   target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria- 
   expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Hi so i got this from boostrap 4.5 navbar. My issue is that when i click on the menu picture it drops to the bottom left corner upon collapse. I want it to stay on the top left corner how do i do that? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place the `id=navbarToggleExternalContent` after the button `navbar-toggler` - like in the snippet below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria- expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- Navbar content -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <div class="bg-dark p-4">
          <h5 class="text-white h4">Collapsed content</h5>
          <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks the navbar-expand-lg expand cause problems though but I fix it